VBA - Loop through different nodes and open them
I need to find and open the corresponding process order for each delivery. I've found a list of the process orders in the DRB (see screenshot below).
Now I want to open each PO separately but I'm a bit stuck.

I thought to loop through each line and check if the text states 'Process Order'. Is there a technical name as well for the specific line? This would be ideal if I use different languages, otherwise I would need to specify each translation in my if-function.
I thought to do it like this but it's not working sadly:
    Set tree = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlBROWSER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]")
    Set ListNodeKeys = tree.GetAllNodeKeys


    For Each nodeKey In ListNodeKeys
     nodeText = tree.GetNodeTextByKey(nodeKey)
     If nodeText = "Process Order" Then
        tree.doubleClickNode
     End If
    Next nodeKey

Does anyone have a better solution for this?
EDIT: I've got it to work with the following:
tree.selectNode (nodeKey)
tree.doubleClickNode (nodeKey)

But I've now seen that I need to firstly open up the 'Sales Order' tree and then find the 'Process Order'.
What is the best way to do this? Because I want to check a specific field in each process order, but I cannot make the loop work to firstly open the 'sales order' and the doubleclick on the 'Process order'. Then check a field and go back to the following process order.
So my current code is as follows:
Set tree = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlBROWSER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]")
Set ListNodeKeys = tree.getallnodekeys

For Each nodeKey In ListNodeKeys
 nodeText = tree.GetNodeTextByKey(nodeKey)
 If nodeText = "Sales Order" Then
    tree.expandNode (nodeKey)
 End If
Next nodeKey

For Each nodeKey In ListNodeKeys
    nodeText = tree.GetNodeTextByKey(nodeKey)
    If nodeText = "Process Order" Then
        tree.selectNode (nodeKey)
        tree.doubleClickNode (nodeKey)
        testExtract = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_5115/tabpKOZE/ssubSUBSCR_5115:SAPLCOKO:5120/ctxtAFPOD-KDPOS").Text
        MsgBox testExtract
    End If
Next nodeKey

So firstly I expand the 'Sales Order' (you can see it on my screenshot above) and then I try to open all process orders. I'm now stuck at opening the first process order.
If I run the code separately, when sales order is already 'open', I can double click on the process order without any problem. Only when I combine the code as shown here above, I cannot get into the process order (so expand sales order + double click on process order).
Anyone an idea of a good solution for the edit here above?

It's a GuiTree object. Yours seems to be one without columns, so a "Simple Tree". You only have a node key and a node text. If the node key is just a counter which increments by 1, you can only use the node text. In your code, what doesn't work please? (line, error code/message, debug information).

Thanks Sandra for the info! So I will need to check the names in different languages.
I"ve found the mistake and I needed to select it first and then double click it and needed to add the nodekey at the end like this: tree.selectNode (nodeKey) tree.doubleClickNode (nodeKey) . But I've run into a new obstacle, I'll try to update my question here above.

I guess you mean that your GuiTree is initially incomplete (contains the level 1 nodes only) and is completed by the backend (to add the nodes of the sub-levels) each time the user expands one parent node, right? (i.e. I guess that double-click is handled by the program to behave like ExpandNode). There's no "good" solution, there are ones with + and -. Please post your code, actual and expected result, I don't understand what the issue is. IMPORTANT TO KNOW: when the backend updates the control, re-instantiate all the variables corresponding to the parts of the screen (findById).

Thanks Sandra, I added the code here above. Hopefully it's clear enough what I'm trying to do.

Almost. You are not saying what issue you have. Note that after expandNode and doubleClickNode, the backend is called in your case (it's not always done, but in your case, it is), so as I said you should re-instantiate the controls (Set tree = session.findById(...)).

Thank you Sandra very much! It helped me a lot! Forgot to give feedback on this topic.
I also found that SAP automatically selected the first node again and I bypassed it by deselecting it again. I've added the solution at the bottom.

The problem was that the first node was selected automatically and messed up the code that followed.
I bypassed it by deselecting it each time:
If nodeText = "Process Order" Then
    tree.selectNode (nodeKey)
    tree.doubleClickNode (nodeKey)
    tree.unselectNode (nodeKey)
    testExtract = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_5115/tabpKOZE/ssubSUBSCR_5115:SAPLCOKO:5120/ctxtAFPOD-KDPOS").Text
    MsgBox testExtract
End If


For your information, the parentheses in tree.selectNode (nodeKey) mean that you force this parameter to be passed by value, which is useless with SAP GUI Scripting. You may simply type tree.selectNode nodeKey (or call tree.selectNode(nodeKey) where the parentheses are required because of call, they don't mean forcing to pass by value).
